# rendering a list inside Element UI checkbox group

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to render some Element UI checkboxes from an array of strings that I'm getting from the server.

```
<el-form-item
  label="Predefined Labels"
>
  // added this div because I wanted to see if I can render correctly using other component
  <div
    v-for="label in predefinedLabels"
    :key="label"
  >
    {{ label }}
  </div>
  <el-checkbox-group
    v-model="userForm.profile.labels"
    size="medium"
  >
    <el-checkbox-button
      v-for="label in predefinedLabels"
      :key="label"
      :label="label"
    >
      {{ label }}
    </el-checkbox-button>
  </el-checkbox-group>
</el-form-item>
```

Using this code, I am rendering the predefinedLabels with the div but not with the checkbox button.

I'm getting the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Flha.png

How can I have a length error about my list when I've already rendered it and seen that it is present and has elements, and, implicitly, length?

Comment: I think you will need to show more of your code to have enough information for us to help solve the problem. Knowing all the template code and the script code would help us see if the issue is somewhere else. I made a codepen to see what might be up and it works as one would expect, which leads me to believe your issue has to be outside of the code chunk you are sharing. https://codepen.io/innerurge1/pen/WNxbYNy?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

I added some comments to the code.

```
<el-form-item
  label="Predefined Labels"
>
  // I added this div because I wanted to see if I can render correctly using other component
  

  // using v-for in div doesn't make sense since predefinedLabels should contain checkboxes.
  // Even if you need multiple checkbox groups you can add v-for to "el-checkbox-group"
  // and make its v-model dynamic.
  <div>
  <el-checkbox-group
    v-model="userForm.profile.labels"
    size="medium"
  >
    <el-checkbox-button
      v-for="label in predefinedLabels"
      :key="label"
      :label="label"
    >
      {{ label }} // you pass the label as a prop, so you shouldn't put it here.
    </el-checkbox-button>
  </el-checkbox-group>
 </div> // closing tag should be here.
</el-form-item>
```

Comment: I only added that div to express the fact that I can render what's in the array using a div, but not using the elements from elementUI. PredefinedLabels is an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bit late but the `length` property is probably called on v-model so check that your `userForm.profile.labels` has the correct data type and is defined.